# How to split a String in java based on integers and return as String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a sting like this:

```
String str = "Aseff1deffre78ijnntke909nnkdhfkk9kshgfks2";
```

I want to split this string where the integer is occurred while reading and
 store the split Strings in an Array of Strings

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [Oracle tutorial on Character Classes within regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) defines numeric literals, maybe this helps.

Comment: `String[] array = str.split("[0-9]+");`

Comment: @ahoxha your array will contain quite a few empty Strings

Comment: @RobinTopper I forgot to add a `+`, I edited it. Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: thanks it is working

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
 public static String[] splitBasedOnInteger(String str) {
        String str2[] = str.split("\\d+");
        for (String s : str2) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        return str2;
```

Comment: what is \\d+ in split method

Comment: It Matches the digits. Equivalent to [0-9]. And + is for one or more occurences. Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Aseff1deffre78ijnntke909nnkdhfkk9kshgfks2");
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        resultList.add(m.group());
    }
    String[] arr = resultList.toArray(new String[resultList.size()]);
```